# How can I upgrade my units with the Ikanda

Tags: civilization-5

I didn't get at all how to use the Ikanda by the in game pedia. In [this](http://civilization.wikia.com/wiki/Ikanda_%28Civ5%29) page, it says 
"[units] have access to the special upgrade path when built in a city with an Ikanda". Is it the only way to receive the Ikanda's bonuses, by creating military units within the city with the Ikanda? It also says, "if you manage to acquire all three promotions of the chain, you will get a very nice army!". How do I "manage to acquire" the promotions?
Thanks.

Comment: the promotions are easy to get. merely use your ikandas to defeat other enemies, then as you slowly earn promotion chances, you can promote your unit till you unlock all the abilities in its particular ability chain.

Comment: @DavidToh Ikandas are a building, they don't defeat enemies. (somehow this reminds me of a similar situation with gazebos)

Comment: It is important to note that ***only*** warriors, spearman, impi, horsemen, knights, and longswordsman receive the benefits from the Ikanda.  Archers and other units do not and the Ikanda acts as a standard barracks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Units built in a city with an Ikanda get a special upgrade (Buffalo Horns) when they are produced.

Due to the way upgrades work in Civ V, having the Buffalo Horns upgrade is what lets you later take the Buffalo Chest and Buffalo Loins upgrades.

So to acquire all 3 upgrades, you simply need to train one of your units up to level 3.

Comment: So, after a unit built in a city with an Ikanda gets promoted by fighting, in addition to the regular bonuses he gets from the upgrade, he also gets the Buffalo Chest and later the Buffalo Loins? Did I understand you correctly? Thanks.

Comment: I would assume that the upgrades are options you can pick when you level, not free upgrades you get in addition.

Comment: @user52549 Michael is correct -- the Buffalo Chest / Loins are additional options (albeit pretty good options!), so you will have to choose them over, say, Shock I, rather than getting the latter 2 for free.